# jQuery not always correctly resizing Bootstrap Panels

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question background:**

I'm using Bootstrap in my View to display a number of Panel to be the same height.

**The Issue:**

The Panels can have differing heights dependent on the image size, title size etc. **As far as I'm aware** there is nothing in Bootstrap that will automatically resize the panels to all be the same size.

I have implemented jQuery to resize the Panels to all be the same height.

The main issue is that sometimes the resized Panels content is overflowing. Often refreshing the page then rectifiies the problem.

Screenshot showing the issue where the content is overflowing the Panel, as denoted by the black arrow:

[image]

After refreshing the problem is rectified as denoted by the green arrow:

[image]

**The Code:**

```
          @foreach (var item in @Model.DisplayItems)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading textOverflow" id="panelHeading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title text-center"><b>@item.Title</b></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <a href="@item.url"><img src="@item.Image" class="picHeight img-rounded img-responsive center-block" /></a>
                            <h4 class="text-center"><b>@item.Price</b></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="@item.url" class="btn btn-success">See More</a></h4>
                            <div class="text-center"><img class="originPic" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+item.img)" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var heights = $(".panel").map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

      maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".panel").height(maxHeight);
});
```

```
<style>
.textOverflow {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.picHeight {
    max-height: 105px;
}

.topOffSet {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.originPic {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Some times images loaded lately make incorrect height.So use $(window).load()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **images loaded lately** you face sometimes this type of issue.
I have change `$(document).ready` to  `$(window).load`

Your code should be.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var heights = $(".panel").map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

      maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".panel").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` is *usually* the right thing to do, but in this case it isn't, at least not without modifications.

The ready event fires when the page's **DOM** is ready. Things like images may not be fetched yet. Given that your panels' heights are dependent on the images within them, this'll result in incorrect calculations if those images haven't loaded when the DOM is ready (as they'll have an unknown/zero height). Reloading fixes it because the images are now in your cache.

You have a couple options:

- Do the resizing in `$(window).load()` instead.
- Add `height="xxx"` to the images to explicitly set their heights.
- Use `setInterval` to periodically resize the panels.